# How are two cell phones having bluetooth paired in terms of hardware and associated software?

Tags: bluetooth

I want to understand, what exactly happens underneath when two phones are bluetooth enabled and paired.

1. Do they share each other's unique bluetooth identity code/number?
2. Can the file transferred to a device be identified later to have been transferred from a particular device?
3. Does a device store the unique identity of another device if they were paired in past?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Bluetooth devices do have each others unique Bluetooth address, for pairing and authentication, a unique key is generated and validated on both the devices, this unique key is never transmitted to each other, would recommend to read the BT SPEC
2. I dont think that you can identify that a file is been transferred from XX device, though you can put a logic and add a extra parameter with which we can identify that if file is transferred via BT, you can device address.
3. If paired in past, a link key is generated and is stored in the device.

Comment: thank you ashish for clarifying.

3. Re: If paired in past, a device has in store the display name of the other device. Does that mean, inside system file, it has the knowledge of the exact unique device which paired with it? Can it trace that device? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, for paired devices, it will store link key in system files,  i didn't understand by trace but it will not do pairing again with other device if link key exists.

Comment: I mean, can the identity of the other paired device be extracted from the current device on the basis of the information it stores about the paired device? Suppose I transfer a file from my device to yours. Can you and under what condition, in future prove that your device was paired with my device and the file came to you from my device?